# Top k "TA" algorithm access count question

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

```
def TA(cls, num_dim, top_k) -> Tuple[list, int]:
    uids_result = []
    uids_score={}
    cnt_access = 0
    topknum=0
    finish=0
    uid2dim2value = defaultdict(dict)                    
    for row in range(10000):
        t=0
        for dim in range(num_dim):  
         uid,value= cls.list_sorted_entities[dim][row]
         uid2dim2value[uid][dim] = value
         t+=value
         
         if uid not in uids_score:
             alldim=list(range(num_dim))
             uids_score[uid] =0
             for count in range(len(alldim)):
                    cnt_access+=1
                    uids_score[uid]+= cls.random_access(uid,alldim[count])
         else :
             cnt_access+=1
        uid_record=sorted(uids_score.keys())
        for count2 in range(len(uids_score)):
            RUID=uid_record[count2]
            if uids_score[RUID]>= t:
                if RUID not in uids_result:     
                 uids_result.append(RUID)
                 topknum+=1
                 if topknum==top_k:
                    finish=1
                    break
        if finish==1:
            break            
    return uids_result, cnt_access
```

Problem is there is sorted list that 10000 students and 10 grades. And we will get the the top_k.

TA algorithm is First, sort the data lists. Second scan the datas in row and add the data and save in 't'(it will be different uid's data obviously). and if you get the new uid, random access the all uid's datas. Third, compare the 't' and sum of scaned uid's data. and if scaned uid's data is larger or same, save the uid in uidresult. If uidresult's num is same with topk, end it.

When I access the data, I add the cnt_access
but in low demension, I got the cnt_access correctly but when in high demension my cnt_count is different from 1~7 error/ for example answer count is 25690 but mine is 25659.
Can you find the error in my code?
#random_access function is get the data.

I think that breaking point is error but in low demension, there is no error.So I can't think the error

Comment: You explained the TA algorithm, but did not first explain for which problem the algorithm is a solution.